# assist with inserting a picture into an html email using php

Tags: php, html

Hello:  been doing html emails with php mail() without any problems - but having a heck of time trying to add a picture properly.  I load in the content of the email into a variable called $messageContent

here is my actual calling of the mail() function:

```
$headers = "From: BBT Admin - " . $emailFrom . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $emailFrom . "\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: ".$bccEmail."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($emailTo,$subject,$messageContent,$headers);
```

All of this works fine - only have problems depending on what I put in the "content" variable...

I basically keep appending to the content variable - building the content one piece at a time...here is the part that is the problem:

```
$messageContent="";

$messageContent.="<a 
href='http://www.example.com'>example.com</a>";
$messageContent.="<br style='clear:both;'/>";
$messageContent.="<br/><br/>";

$messageContent.="<img src='http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Capture_bbtmap3.png'/>";
```

So this doesnt work that well - so if anyone can help on this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<img src='http://example.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/03/Capture_bbtmap3.png'/>` having that split into two lines as shown in your post, will definitely break it here. Notice the space also?

Comment: actually there is no space in my script - but it turned out that way when pasting it in here - i will see if i can edit it ...

Comment: another thing; it's unknown if you have more lines above your `$messageContent.="<a 
href='http://www.example.com'>example.com</a>";` - If not, then you need to first assign it as `$messageContent = "";`. - Check for errors also and use `var_dump()`.

Comment: ok it is now the way it is in my script - thanks for pointing that out

Comment: actually there was more content above and the first line just assigned it without appending; so i threw in a line like you said to illustrate what i have in my script...it is assigned ok...

Comment: looks ok to me, I can't see how that could fail.

Comment: sometimes single quote on src attr will fail.  try double (esc like \").  also unless its xhtml no need for slash before &gt; `/>` ..

Comment: when you go to img url in browser does it show up?

Comment: actually i found the problem - for some reason the href before the image was messing it up...but when i wrapped the href in a "p" tag - then the image showed up fine in the email...thanks for everyones help...